# Copying byte array with Marshal.Copy from IntPtr using C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm using an unmanaged library, which generates grayscale images (about 100x200 pixels, more or less). An image is contained within a struct, which looks like this in C:

```
typedef struct abs_image {
    ABS_DWORD Width;
    ABS_DWORD Height;
    ABS_DWORD ColorCount;
    ABS_DWORD HorizontalDPI;
    ABS_DWORD VerticalDPI;
    ABS_BYTE ImageData[ABS_VARLEN];
} ABS_IMAGE
```

```
typedef unsigned int     ABS_DWORD;
typedef unsigned char     ABS_BYTE;
```

And here my C# wrapper struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ABS_IMAGE {
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint ColorCount;
    public uint HorizontalDPI;
    public uint VerticalDPI;
    public IntPtr ImageData;
}
```

Grabbing the image and marshallign the `ABS_IMAGE` struct works just fine. In a previous version, I tried using a byte array with fixed length for ImageData, which crashed sometimes. This happened, I think, because the image size is not fix.
Now I try to read the image byte array at later time, when I can calulate the real array length before. Here the relevant code:

```
ABS_Type_Defs.ABS_IMAGE img =
    (ABS_Type_Defs.ABS_IMAGE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
    pImage,
    typeof(ABS_Type_Defs.ABS_IMAGE));

int length = ((int)img.Height - 1) * ((int)img.Width - 1);
byte[] data = new byte[length];

Marshal.Copy(img.ImageData, data, 0, length);
```

Now my problem: Every time I want to execute Marshal.Copy to read the image bytes, I get an `AccessViolationException`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what is happening. Your struct is what is known as a variable length struct. The pixel data is containined inline in the struct, starting at the offset to `ImageData`.

```
typedef struct abs_image {
    ABS_DWORD Width;
    ABS_DWORD Height;
    ABS_DWORD ColorCount;
    ABS_DWORD HorizontalDPI;
    ABS_DWORD VerticalDPI;
    ABS_BYTE ImageData[ABS_VARLEN];
} ABS_IMAGE
```

Your API returns `pImage` which is an `IntPtr` that points to unmanaged data of type `ABS_IMAGE`. However, if you look at the native code then you will see that `ABS_VARLEN` is equal to `1`. This is because the `struct` has to be defined statically at compile time. In reality the pixel data will have length determined by the height, width and colour count fields.

You can carry on using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get at most of the fields. But you can't get at the `ImageData` field that way. That's going to need a little more work.

Declare the struct like this instead:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ABS_IMAGE {
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint ColorCount;
    public uint HorizontalDPI;
    public uint VerticalDPI;
    public byte ImageData;
}
```

When you need to get the image data do this:

```
IntPtr ImageData = pImage + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(ABS_IMAGE), "ImageData");
Marshal.Copy(ImageData, data, 0, length);
```

If you are not yet on .net 4 then you need casting to make the arithmetic compile:

```
IntPtr ImageData = (IntPtr) (pImage.ToInt64() + 
    Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(ABS_IMAGE), "ImageData").ToInt64());
```

Finally, I think you are calculating `length` incorrectly. Surely you need to use `Height*Width`. Also you have not accounted for the color depth. For example, 32 bit color will be 4 bytes per pixel.